# Nested for loops < operator should not work

Tags: c

I have to create the half of a pyramid in C, and it works, but I dont understand why in the second loop when I evaluate j < i still execute the code in the curly braces, if j = 0 and i = 0, they are equal, so i is no greater than 
j...so what's the difference between using < and <= in this case?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("#");
        }
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't. You are misreading something. Change the inner printf to `printf("%d %d ", i, j);`.

Comment: I recommend you also print I and J.  It will make more sense.

Comment: Yep, I have tested your code at the http://cpp.sh. It works, as expected.

Comment: Whatever evidence makes you believe that block is executing even when `j == i`, it belongs in your question, and how you drew your conclusion based on said-same. Adding instrumentation, as others have advised, will clarify far more about what is going on, rather than assuming you already know.

Comment: Note that the outer loop runs 5 times (from 0 to 4) but creates a pyramid 4 units high. That might have been the source of confusion.

Comment: This would be the perfect time to start your debugger and single-step through this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = 0
    j = 0, break out of loop
i = 1
    j = 0, print #
    j = 1, break out of loop
i = 2
    j = 0, print #
    j = 1, print #
    j = 2, break out of loop
i = 3
    j = 0, print #
    j = 1, print #
    j = 2, print #
    j = 3, break out of loop
i = 4
    j = 0, print #
    j = 1, print #
    j = 2, print #
    j = 3, print #
    j = 4, break out of loop
i = 5, break out of loop
```

Comment: then it works only because I'm printing a blank line in the beginning?

Comment: yeah, pretty much, if you want a 4 high pyramid without the blank line change the `<=` in the `i` loop to `<' and the `<` in the `j` loop to `<=`

Comment: You are right, Thanks Stephen Docy!

Comment: Or avoid printing the blank line with `if (i) printf("\n");` (which should be `putchar ('\n');` because you don't need to call `printf` for a single-character)

Answer (score 1):

To print out a 4-high pyramid without a leading blank line

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, it doesn't work (the way you are expecting it to). One way to see what is going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        printf("%d>",i);
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, only with a blank line in the beginning

Comment: @ThisNameWasTaken, yes but the inner loop does not execute on the first iteration, because i=0 is not less than j=0 thus no # is printed.

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("#");
        }
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

is working as it should work. The first # is printed when i = 1 and j=0. So, you are somewhere misunderstanding the concept of for loop in c.
In C language, first the initialization i.e first argument is called and then the second argument that is loop control is accessed and if condition is true then the loop is accessed.